# pcd_viewer crashes after installing electric

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

aa755@abhishekHPUbuntu:~$ rosrun pcl_visualization pcd_viewer fridge.pcd

> Loading fridge.pcd /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl_addons/pcl_visualization/bin/pcd_viewer: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl_addons/pcl_visualization/bin/pcd_viewer: undefined symbol: _ZN17pcl_visualization28PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle3NewEv

I have unstable, diamondback and electric installed. but my .bashrc sets the environment variables for electric
source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11467/pcd_viewer-crashes-after-installing-electric/) by [aa755](https://answers.ros.org/users/303/aa755/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-10-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-10-09**:
+1  I have the same problem when trying to run pcd_viewer with downloaded RoboEarth models.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-02-29**:
Closing question as there is no activity from OP

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that part of the problem is that both perception_pcl/pcl and perception_pcl_addons/pcl_visualization produce libraries called "libpcl_visualization.so".  The linker sees the version from perception_pcl/pcl first, so ignores the one from perception_pcl_addons/pcl_visualization.

I messed around with renaming the library from  perception_pcl_addons/pcl_visualization to be libpcl_visualization_addons.so.  That fixed the undefined variables, but pcd_viewer and pcd_viewer_simple both produce blank screens.  Well, pcd_viewer_simple has the nice red, blue, green axes that follow the mouse, but that's all.  The same .pcd files (from bag_to_pcd) worked fine on a colleague's CloudViewer from the PCL windows download (I'm on Ubuntu 11.04).

---

Originally posted by [DanDee](https://answers.ros.org/users/1241/dandee/) with karma: 31 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The viewer works fine, but the viewpoint was off - the object being viewed was way off the edge of the visible windows.  Randomly moving the mouse around, or using the "r" key brought it back into view.

---

Originally posted by [DanDee](https://answers.ros.org/users/1241/dandee/) with karma: 31 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pcd_viewer and pcd_viewer_simple from opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/bin work fine.  The displayed image is sized to the display window and oriented correctly.  The versions of pcd_viewer and pcd_viewer_simple (and bag_viewer_simple) from perception_pcl_addons/pcl_visualization/bin have the image far off screen and it's rotated around a horizontal axis that's parallel to the display's glass (mirrored top/bottom, mirrored towards user / away from user.

---

Originally posted by [DanDee](https://answers.ros.org/users/1241/dandee/) with karma: 31 on 2011-10-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1